# Javascript: how to reset a form's fields to original text values after pressing reset button

Tags: javascript, forms

basically i have this form. when i press "send message" button, if there is a field with no value in it, the field comes back with a red error message in it. but when i press reset, it does not change the values to black text, and the text stays red.. how do i fix this?

```
<form id="contact" action="" onsubmit="checkContactForm( this ); return false;">
<p>Fill in the form below to send me a message!</p>    
<p>
  <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
  <input name="firstname" id="firstname" onfocus="resetField( this );" />
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
  <input name="lastname" id="lastname" onfocus="resetField( this );" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="email">E-mail address:</label>
  <input name="email" id="email" onfocus="resetField( this );" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" onfocus="resetField( this );"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
</p>
</form>
```

and this javascript:

```
var requiredFields = [ "firstname", "lastname", "email", "message" ];

function checkContactForm( theForm ) {
  for ( i in requiredFields ) {
    var fieldName = requiredFields[ i ];
    var theField = theForm[ fieldName ];

    if ( !theField.value || theField.value == "Error" ) {
      theField.style.color = "#f66";
      theField.value = "Error";
      var emptyFields = true;
    }
  }

  if ( !emptyFields ) {
    theForm.submit();
  }
}

function resetField( theField ) {
  if ( theField.value == "Error" ) {
    theField.value = "";
    theField.style.color = "#000";
  }
}
```

Comment: just making sure, what you need is ""theField.value = "";.."" to contain some value(default value) in your resetField function.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting a form only resets the values, so you need to add a listener to the reset button to change the colour back, e.g.

```
<input type="reset" onclick="resetForm(this);">
```

and in the function something like:

```
function resetForm(el) {
  var form = el.form;
  for (var els = form.elements, i=els.length; i; ) {
    els[--i].style.color = #000000;
  }
}
```

The above is just an example, you'll need to tailor it to suit.

Also, it's not a good idea to use for..in over an array. Where you have:

```
for ( i in requiredFields ) {
```

you are better off to do something like:

```
var requiredFields = {'firstname':'', 'lastname':'', 'email':'', 'message':''}; 
var element, elements = form.elements;

for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  element = elements[i];

  if (element in requiredFields) {

    if (!element.value || element.value == 'Error') {
      ...
```

Also, if the form controls have a name, they rarely need an ID as well.